# How to set a Price List if i want to put discount buy 2 get 1 free in Odoo 8?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

For Example i want to put discount on different type of product(not same categories) and a specific product it's also a different type of category should be free..

other wise free product has price if customer want to bye single product at Point of sale

Example

Category A (product)      Category B (Product)    Category C (Product)

1(price)             +     1(price)             +     1  Free

Else Free product sale alone it should price